# Cannot find who has file open

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that find who has a file opened. The files are on network drives that use our old username as authenication. Our username use to be john.doe, it is now a number 12345. The code does not find a username. Is there something I'm overlooking or need to do to find out who has the file opened? Curious if and when we are on the actual new network that host the username 12345, that we will be able to find see the username 12345. The error message i do get is:

"The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

```
Public Shared Function GetFileOwner(ByVal strFileName)
    Try
        Dim objSD As Object = Nothing
        Dim objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
        Dim objFileSecuritySettings =
    objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strFileName & "'")
        Dim intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)

        If intRetVal = 0 Then
            GetFileOwner = objSD.Owner.Name
        Else
            GetFileOwner = "Unknown"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error :" & Date.Today.ToString & " " & ex.Message)
        GetFileOwner = "Unknown"
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that this option is available on your server? You can easily do this..

Open the Computer Management snap-in on your file server (or connect to the server remotely from the management console running on your computer) and go to System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Open files. The list of files opened on the remote server is displayed on the right side of the window.

Many times i tried to access my server on the domain and it gave me that error, domains hate custom made apps :)

Comment: I don't have that permission to access server infor.